# mysqli_real_escape_query, query seems ok, but nothing written in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form, method="post" where users can input info like their name and email, that then get's inserted in a database. For safety I tried to use mysqli_real_escape_string.
Now, the query says it worked but no data get's inserted in my database. Without the escape everything worked allright too (except for not being escaped)

CODE:
(Updated missing quote, it's there in my original code, so that's not the problem. Sry for that)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$email = explode('@',$_POST['mail']); //explode because I only need the prefix
$maila = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$email[0]);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);

$query = "INSERT INTO base(mail,name) VALUES ('$maila','$name')";
if(mysqli_query($link,$query)) {
          echo "SUCCES";
        }
        else {
          echo "FAIL";}
}
```

So when I process the query, `SUCCES` comes up but the mail and name don't arrive in my table.

I googled and searched here, but couldn't find a solution (excuse me if I overlooked it). I also hope I posted enough of my code.

Extra info:

Before the SQL-query goes into action the form is checked in a way like

```
if($_POST['name'] == null){echo "an error message";}
```

EDIT; FULL CODE (I am aware that there are mistakes/stupid things in my if-statements, but these work fine without escaping so I will check these later)

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      if($_POST['ios'] == null ) {$resios = 0;} else {$resios = $_POST['ios'];}
      if($_POST['android'] == null) {$resand = 0;} else {$resand = $_POST['android'];}
      if($_POST['windows'] == null) {$reswin = 0;}  else {$reswin = $_POST['windows'];}
    //Check for errors
      if($_POST['naam'] == null) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Gelieve een naam in te vullen</span><br />";}
      if($_POST['opleiding'] == 0) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Selecteer een opleiding</span><br />";}
      if($resios > $ios) {$resios = $ios; echo "<span class=\"error\">Aantal iOS tablets overschreden. Maximum " . $ios . " tablets beschikbaar.</span><br />";}
      if($resand > $android) {$resand = $android; echo "<span class=\"error\">Aantal Android tablets overschreden. Maximum " . $android . " tablets beschikbaar.</span><br />";}
      if($reswin > $windows) {$reswin = $reswin; echo "<span class=\"error\">Aantal Windows tablets overschreden. Maximum " . $windows . " tablets beschikbaar.</span><br />";}
      if($resios < 0) {$resios = 0; echo "<span class=\"error\">Aantal tablets kan niet lager zijn dan 0!</span><br />";}
      if($resand < 0) {$resand = 0; echo "<span class=\"error\">Aantal tablets kan niet lager zijn dan 0!</span><br />";}
      if($reswin < 0) {$reswin = 0; echo "<span class=\"error\">Aantal tablets kan niet lager zijn dan 0!</span><br />";}
      if($_POST['terms'] != 'on') {echo "<span class=\"error\">Reglement moet aanvaard worden.</span><br />";}
      if($resios == 0 && $resand == 0 && $reswin == 0) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Er moet minstens 1 tablet gereserveerd worden</span>";}
      else {

//ESCAPE + INSERT
        $email = explode('@',$_POST['mail']);
        $maila = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$email[0]);
        $opleiding = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['opleiding']);
        $naam = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['naam']);
        $datum = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$datum);
        $resios = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$resios);
        $resand = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$resand);
        $reswin = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$reswin);
        $opmerking = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['opmerking']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO reservaties(oplid,naam,datum,ios,android,windows,emailname,opmerking) VALUES ('$opleiding','$naam','$datum','$resios','$resand', '$reswin','$maila', '$opmerking')";
        if(mysqli_query($link,$query)) {
          echo "<p class=\"succes\">U hebt succesvol " . $resios . " iOS-tablets, " . $resand . " Android-tablets en " . $reswin . " Windows-tablets gereserveerd op " . $disdate . "</p>";
          echo "<p>Een bevesting van uw reservatie via mail? <form style=\"display:inline;\" target=\"_blank\" action=\"print.php\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"mail\" value=\"".$maila."\" />@arteveldehs.be <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"naam\" value=\"".$_POST['naam']."\"/><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"datum\" value=\"". $datum . "\"/><input type=\"submit\" name=\"print\" value=\"mail\"></form></p>";
        }


        else {
          echo "<p class=\"error\">Er is een fout opgetreden. Probeer opnieuw, of neem contact op met de <a href=\"mailto:mediatheek.kantienberg@arteveldehs.be\">Mediatheek</a>.</p>";}
        }
    }
    ?>
<!-- my form-->
<form action="#" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td colspan="3"><span class="required">*</span> = verplicht veld</td></tr>  
<tr><td>Naam:<span class="required">*</span></td><td><input type="text" name="naam" placeholder="Naam" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="voornaam.naam" />@arteveldehs.be</td></tr>
<tr><td>Opleiding:<span class="required">*</span></td><td colspan="2"> 
<select name="opleiding">
<option value="0">Selecteer een opleiding</option>
<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT SUM(ios) as iostotal,SUM(android) as androidtotal,SUM(windows) as windowstotal FROM reservaties WHERE '$datum' = datum";
      $check2 = mysqli_query($link,$sql2) or die(mysql_error());         
        while ($free2 = mysqli_fetch_array($check2)) {
            $iosall = 16;
            $andall = 18;
            $winall = 20;
        $ios2 = $iosall - $free2['iostotal']; 
        $android2 = $andall - $free2['androidtotal'];
        $windows2 = $winall - $free2['windowstotal'];
        }
$opleidingen = "SELECT * FROM opleidingen";
$values = mysqli_query($link,$opleidingen) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($values)) {
$oplid = $row['oplid'];$opleiding = $row['opleiding'];
echo "<option value=\"".$oplid."\">".$opleiding."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Aantal iOS</td><td><input type="text" name="ios" placeholder="<?= $ios2;?>" ><span class="max">(maximum <?= $ios2;?> beschikbaar)</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Aantal Android</td><td><input type="text" name="android" placeholder="<?= $android2;?>" ><span class="max">(maximum <?= $android2;?> beschikbaar)</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Aantal Windows</td><td><input type="text" name="windows" placeholder="<?= $windows2;?>" ><span class="max">(maximum <?= $windows2;?> beschikbaar)</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Opmerking:</td><td colspan="2"><textarea maxlength="512" rows="5" cols="50" name="opmerking" placeholder="Bv. Tijdstip van oppikken/terugbrengen - vraag aan de mediatheek - ..." ></textarea></td></tr></table>

<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="on" /> Hiermee verklaar ik me akkoord met het <a target="_blank" href="reglement.php">reglement</a> dat geldt voor het gebruik van deze tablets.<span class="required">*</span>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reserveer"/></p>
</form>
<?php }
?>
```

DATABASE reservaties

```
resid   int(9) PRIMARY KEY  
oplid   int(9)
naam    varchar(55) latin1_swedish_ci
datum   date
ios varchar(3)
android varchar(3)
windows varchar(3)
emailname
opmerking   varchar(512)    latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Missing quote in `VALUES ('$maila','$name');` do `VALUES ('$maila','$name')";`

Comment: Sorry, it was there in my original code. It went missing when editing my code to put it here.

Comment: You need to post full code then, including your HTML form. And DB schema

Comment: Plus, are you sure you didn't mean `(maila,name)` since you're using `$maila` I need to know what your DB schema is. And maybe you didn't name your submit button. Again, hard to tell without seeing full code.

Comment: Another thing. If you're using the name for a table that doesn't exist, will also not show you any errors, unless you have error reporting "on" http://www.php.net/mysqli_error. You're probably trying to figure it out for yourself right now, but I'm not going to stick around for an undetermined length of time, in finding out what the exact problem is. If I don't see the full picture, then I can't draw you a straight line.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just added full code (language mostly in dutch). I only posted a small, edited bit, because everything worked before I tried adding mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: Your initial question/code far exceeds what you posted now. Why didn't post it in the first place? Even if it's Dutch (which I know a bit), yet that doesn't matter to me, it's the PHP/SQL that is important. If you say that it worked before you added `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, then check to see if your DB connection is `mysqli_*` and not `mysql_*` - and the `#` in `<form action="#" method="post">` take it out so it reads as `<form action="" method="post">` because I gather you're running everything in one page.

Comment: I also noticed you're using a `mysql_*` based function `or die(mysql_error())` which needs to be `or die(mysqli_error())` check to see if you don't have any other `mysql_*` based functions.

Comment: I take it that you do have your DB connection in your working code, but you didn't post it? `$link` looks to be your DB connection variable, but you didn't post it in your original and edit if you are indeed connected to DB. If not, then you need to put it in your code. I don't know what else to tell you that will be of any further help. If not connected, then add `$link = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");`

Comment: include('dbinfo.php');
`$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "xxx";
$dbpass = "xxx";
$dbdatabase = "xxx";

$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,$dbdatabase);
`

Comment: Just changed the mysql_error to mysqli_error and now it works fine again.

No clue what did break it, but it seems fixed now. Thanks for thinking along and helping me.

Comment: You're welcome and always glad to see when something gets resolved. I suspect that the `mysql_error` being a `mysql_*` based function, breaks the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP's [`original posted question`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22046676/1)

You have a missing quote for your query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO base(mail,name) VALUES ('$maila','$name') ;

                                             // right there  --^
```

do:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO base(mail,name) VALUES ('$maila','$name')";
```

Using error reporting would have helped shown the error **http://www.php.net/mysqli_error**

Since no error was thrown (at you), this tells me that you are not using error reporting.

```
if (!mysqli_query($link,$query))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

These `or die(mysql_error())` need to be changed to `or die(mysqli_error())` since `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` based functions do not mix with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have missed to close `"`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `base` (`mail`,`name`) VALUES ('$maila','$name')";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed  end `"` in your query string.
replace this line:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO base(mail,name) VALUES ('$maila','$name');
```

by this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO base(mail,name) VALUES ('$maila','$name')";
```